# How to update Bootstrap 2.2 to latest 3.2?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In one of my old project I am using **Bootstrap 2.2** .How to update the Bootstrap version to 3.4 without code change and I need new features in **Bootstrap 3.2**. How to use 2 versions of BS without any issue?

Comment: if you change to 3.2 than you also need to changes your html structure and class applied on it.Simple answer you can't

Answer (score 0):

If your code isn't very complicated, give [Bootstrap Upgrader](http://code.divshot.com/bootstrap3_upgrader/) a try, it works pretty decently on "vanilla" Bootstrap 2 sites. Bootply has [its own tool](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/) as well, but in my own experience, BS Upgrader works better, at least until a few months ago when I used it fr the last time.

This being said, you'll need to take a look at the officila [Bootstrap Migration Page](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/) to see what has changed, because it won't do you much benefit to migrate your site if you don't have any idea about what has changed

Answer (score 0):

Updating your bootstrap is not generally encouraged. Many classes used in old bootstrap are not available in newer versions. You will need to change your HTML and CSS for the same.

For eg- Class for alignment in bootstrap 2.2 are named as span1, span2 and so on where as classes in bootstrap 3.2 for same purpose are named as col-md-1 , col-md-2 and so on for responsive grid structure.

Using new bootstrap can distort your current HTML structure and design also.